# Using CMakeLists.txt with multiple targets with different flags

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I'm trying to compile the following file, into two different executables, using CMakeLists.txt.

This file is: `main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

int main(int, char**) {
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    assert(0);
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the `CMakeLists.txt` file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(multi_Tar VERSION 0.1.0)


SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3 -DNDEBUG")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O0")
add_executable(multi_Tar main.cpp)

add_executable(tests main.cpp)
set_target_properties(tests PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE}")
```

---

This solution does not work. When I run `./tests` I'm not getting an assertion error.

---

The motivation is using the same `CMakeLists.txt` for testing validity, and to benchmark the same code.

---

Thanks for the help.

### Edit after @squareskittles answer:

Thanks for the answer!

(Including the code for the answer:)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(multi_Tar VERSION 0.1.0)

add_executable(multi_Tar main.cpp)
# Add the compile options for multi_Tar.
target_compile_definitions(multi_Tar PRIVATE -O3 -DNDEBUG)

add_executable(tests main.cpp)
# Add the compile options for tests.
target_compile_definitions(multi_Tar PRIVATE -O0)
```

I tried using your solution, but I got the following error:

```
<command-line>: error: macro names must be identifiers
<command-line>: error: macro names must be identifiers
CMakeFiles/multi_Tar.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/multi_Tar.dir/main.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/multi_Tar.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:104: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/multi_Tar.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/multi_Tar.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:105: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried changing the `CMakeLists.txt` a bit, but did not manage to get it to work.

Also, should the last line in your solution be:

```
target_compile_definitions(multi_Tar PRIVATE -O0)
```

or

```
target_compile_definitions(tests PRIVATE -O0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the CMake code, the `tests` executable should **not** produce an assertion error. You added the `NDEBUG` compile definition, which *disables* the `assert` macro per the [`assert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cassert/assert/) documentation.

If you want to apply compile flags to *specific* CMake targets, you should use the target-specific CMake commands, such as [`target_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/command/target_compile_options.html) and [`target_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/command/target_compile_definitions.html#command:target_compile_definitions). I'm not sure where you found this CMake code, but manually modifying the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS*` variables is *discouraged* and typically unnecessary, especially in more recent versions of CMake.

Try something like this instead, to apply the `NDEBUG` flag **only** to the `multi_Tar` target:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(multi_Tar VERSION 0.1.0)

add_executable(multi_Tar main.cpp)
# Add the compile options for multi_Tar.
target_compile_options(multi_Tar PRIVATE -O3 -DNDEBUG)

add_executable(tests main.cpp)
# Add the compile options for tests.
target_compile_options(tests PRIVATE -O0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). I could not get it to compile, not sure why.

Comment: @TheHolyJoker See updated response, yes, the last line should be specific to the `tests` target. And fixed the CMake code, the correct command here should be `target_compile_options`.